# wp simple shopping cart quantity

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, paypal, shopping-cart

i'm using the wp simple shopping cart plugin to create an e-shop.
All works, but i need to add a quantity input box that modify the add cart button.

something similar to:

```
[wp_cart_button name="prodct1" price="100.00" shipping="0.00001" quantity="100"]
```

obviusly in this way it doesn't work.
Someone know if there is a way to do that?

Thank you!
[image: IMG]